# msadox28.tlb is not a valid .Net assembly file while registering it

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, adox

I am developing application with vb.net (2015) and MS Access database. I can work fine with existing database. I have now situation where I need to create database programmatically, for billing purpose. It is the situation where each folder will contain database for company/firm selection.

After searching on the internet / StackOverflow I learned about ADOX. Even got the ready code for it. I applied it in my coding.

1. Adding reference of Microsoft ADO extend 2.8  and 6.0
2. Created variable Adx as new Adox.catalog
3. Then finally wrote Adx.create(olejet provider conn string with data source)

In this step I get an error

> COM Class not registered

So I tried to register `msadox.dll` and `msadox28.tlb` with `regsvr32` and `regasm` but at that time I get another error:

> msadox.dll get registered successfully but error gives in msadox28.tlb
> Fail to load -file- becuase it is not a valid .net assembly file

Now I am stuck at this point.

My system is Windows 10 64 bit. I tried to target cpu x86, and any cpu but it didn't work. I got many questions and answer here but didn't understand it.

EDIT:

I tried following connection string and it worked, but it creates old 2000-2003 mdb file. i want to use new access file .accdb

String is :

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\VBProj\Testing\test.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5
```

EDIT : on 20/9/2021 - MON

First of all Thank you very much @Jimi, your suggestion to use ACE.16 and cleaning solution worked. Thanks a lot

I use the following steps to create MS Access database using ADOX in VB.NET:

1. Project Menu > Add Reference > COM Section > Select Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DLL and security
2. Write connection string at program entry point (form load/sub main) -> `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=D:\VBProj\Testing\test.accdb`, assign it to variable `connString`
3. Declare adox catalog globally like `Public gAdxCat As New ADOX.Catalog`
4. Use its method `gAdxCat.create(connString)`
5. That's all - DONE

Again thanks to @jimi

Comment: Did you add a Reference, in your Project, to `Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security`? This creates the Interop assembly in `\[Project]\Obj\Debug`. -- `Embed Interop Types` is usually set to `true` by default.

Comment: Yes reference is added

Comment: Yes @jmcilhinney, i am also surprised when i posted the question. i just wanted to bold one line of message but whole message became bold. but now i can see it in normal/regular font in my system.

Comment: Remove the reference to version `2.8`. BTW, you don't need the old Jet Engine, you can also use the new Providers, e.g., `ACE.12` and `ACE.16`, to build a database using ADOX. Using Jet, your application needs to target x86.

Comment: @Jimi
I removed reference of 2.8 and used following conn. string but gives error. conn. string is : Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\VBProj\Testing\test.accdb. ERROR IS : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Class not registered'

Comment: As I mentioned before - in relation to what you have posted in the OP - don't use the Jet 4.0 driver to build a database, use `ACE.12` or `ACE.16` (possibly the latter) with ADOX 6.0. That's all. -- The exception you refer to in the comment is not related to ADOX, but to the ACE Engine. Also, I don't see where that connection string is used. It should in `[Catalog].Create([Connection String])`. You should post all your code inside the body of your question, not in comments.

Comment: If you remove a reference from a Project, you need to clean the Solution and then rebuild it. Of course, check whether you have used that reference in code somewhere. -- Since you can use JET 4.0, then your app is built to target x86, otherwise JET 4.0, which is x86 only, would not work. Your `ACE` driver is probably installed using the x64 version, so you won't find it when running your x86 app. -- Build your app to target AnyCPU and deselect the `Prefer 32-bit` option.

Comment: Thank you @Jimi - Your suggestion to use ACE.16 worked, thank you very much for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my question (helped by @jimi)

following are the steps to create msaccess database using ADOX in VB.NET and error occurs mention in original questions.

1-Project Menu > Add Reference > COM Section > Select Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DLL and security (remove ref of 2.8)

2-write connection string at program entry point (form load/sub main) -> "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=D:\VBProj\Testing\test.accdb" assign it to variable connString

3-declare adox catalog globally like Public gAdxCat As New ADOX.Catalog

4-User its method gAdxCat.create(connString)

5-Thats all DONE

again thanks to @jimi